# How will I return back to the menu if value entered is wrong?

Tags: python-3.x

So I have this code

```
import csv
def menu():
    print ("""
         1.Enter airport details
         2.Enter flight details
         3.Enter price plan and calculate profit
         4. Clear data
         5.Quit
            """)
menu()
b = input("What would you like to choose?")
if b == '4':
    print('Goodbye')

if b == '1':
    a = input('Enter three letter code: ')
    if a == 'LPL' or a == 'BOH':
        d = input('Enter overseas airport code: ')
        airport_info = open('airports.csv', 'r')
        csvreader = csv.DictReader(airport_info,delimiter = ',', fieldnames = ('overseasCode','overseasName','distLPL','distBOH'))
        for row in csvreader:
            if row['overseasCode'] == d:
                print(row['overseasName'],d)
```

so if the user inputs something different then LPL or BOH an error code should show up and the user returned back to the menu to try again. I think it must be a while loop but I am not sure how to implement it so can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, indeed, a while loop. Just like that:

```
flag = False
while flag == False:
    menu()
    b = input("What would you like to choose?")
    if b == '4':
        print('Goodbye')

    if b == '1':
        a = input('Enter three letter code: ')
        if a == 'LPL' or a == 'BOH':
            flag = True
            ...
        else:
            print("Error")
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside a `while` loop, just `break` !!

```
while True:
    menu()
    b = input("What would you like to choose?")
    if b == '4':
        print('Goodbye')

    if b == '1':
        a = input('Enter three letter code: ')
        if a == 'LPL' or a == 'BOH':
            break 
            ...
        else:
            print("Error")
```